# Isomorphism classes of graphs and their automorphism groups

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

*[Edit: As suggested by Chris in his answer I rephrased the question to make it better readable.]*

The usual way to define a (labelled) graph is as a subset of edges $E \subseteq V^2 = V \times V$ over a set of vertices $V$, i.e. as a pair $\langle V,E\subseteq V^2\rangle$. 
Restricting oneself to sets of vertices $V_n := [n] = \lbrace 0,\dots,n-1\rbrace$ this definition is equivalent with $n$ by $n$ matrices over $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ (*adjacency matrices*), i.e. functions from $[n]^2$ to $[2]$, the set of all $n$-graphs thus being defined as

$$G_n := [2]^{[n]^2}$$

Let $S_n$ be the group of permutations of $[n]$. Define the usual equivalence relation for graphs $g,g' \in G_n$ by

$$g \simeq g' :\equiv (\exists \pi \in S_n)\ \pi g = g'$$

with $(\pi g)_{ij} = g_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}$. Let $\Gamma_n = G_n/\simeq$ be the set of **isomorphism classes of graphs** over $V_n$. Let $\gamma = [g] = \lbrace g'\ |\ g\simeq g'\rbrace$, i.e.

$$\qquad\qquad\quad\gamma  = [g] = \lbrace g' \in G_n\ |\ (\exists \pi \in S_n)\ \pi g = g'\rbrace = \lbrace g' \ |\ (\exists \pi )\ \pi g = g'\rbrace\qquad[1]$$

be the isomorphism class of $g$. 
Associated with such an isomorphism class $\gamma$ is its **automorphism group** $\text{Aut}(\gamma)\subseteq S_n$ of permutations which relate the "elements" of $\gamma = [g]$ with each other, i.e.

$$\text{Aut}(\gamma) = \text{Aut}([g]) = \lbrace \pi \in S_n\ |\ (\exists g' \in G_n)\ \pi g = g'\rbrace = \lbrace \pi \ |\ (\exists g' )\ \pi g = g'\rbrace\qquad[2]$$

To be honest: I was taken by surprise by the formal similarity of the two definitions [1] and [2]. Isomorphism classes and automorphism groups seem to be something like specifically “dual concepts”.

> How can this be explained somehow more “deeply”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to speak of "graphs" and "isomorphism classes of graphs" (rather than labelled and unlabelled graphs). For me your labelled graph is just a graph.

An isomorphism class of graphs with vertex set $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is an orbit of the symmetric group $S_n$ on subsets of the set of unordered pairs from $V$. Your first formula encodes this fact.

For the second formula, the points of an orbit of a permutation group can be identified with cosets of a point stabilizer; in your context a point stabilizer is the automorphism group of a graph in the isomorphism class.

Comment: An isomorphism class of graphs would be a an orbit under $S_n$ of *collections* of unordered pairs (i.e. possible edge sets).

Comment: @anon: thanks, I've amended it.